# How can we associate content type to SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, content-type, power-automate, workflow2013

With the recent update from Microsoft wherein SharePoint Workflow 2010 will be retiring on November 2020, how can we replicate SharePoint 2010 workflow that uses content type?

I have 52 SharePoint list that are attached in a content type. I created a 2010 worfklow that is also attached in the said content type. The workflow is working well for 5 years now but with the latest announcement, I don't think my 2010 workflow will be working smoothly beyond November 2020.

What are the workaround that I can do about this? Please don't let me make 52 same workflows running on my site :(

Our version of SharePoint is SharePoint Online.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: SharePoint Online @GaneshSanap

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2010 Workflows will retire in SharePoint Online. If you are working with SharePoint online,  you can convert the SharePoint workflows to PowerAutomate, but you need to build it from the start.

SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2013 based workflows will continue to be supported on SharePoint server until 2026.

Reference:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/sharepoint-2010-workflow-retirement-1ca3fff8-9985-410a-85aa-8120f626965f

Comment: Hi @lisa Can Power Automate handle list content type?